# Asp.net Validators not validating on client side working fine on server side

Tags: asp.net

when i submit form it get submitted and on server side it not runs the code inside page.validate method.
page get refreshed and then displays the message field is required.

if i use submitbehaviour= false in button property form never get submitted. I am using validation group as well.

[image]

```
 <div class="inner-pages">
    <section class="royal-add-property-area section_100">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" id="regForm" style="margin-top: 80px;">
                    <div class="single-add-property">
                        <h3>Basic Informations</h3>
                        <div class="property-form-group">
                            <div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <p>
                                            <label for="title">Business Title *</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="title" runat="server" clientidmode="static" id="txtTitle" class="username" placeholder="Enter your Business Title" >
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <p>
                                            <label for="description">Business Description *</label>
                                            <textarea runat="server" id="txtDescription" name="pro-dexc" placeholder="Describe about your Business" ></textarea>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                        <p class="no-mb">
                                            <label for="price">Speciality *</label>
                                            <input type="text" runat="server" id="txtSpciality" placeholder="Speciality should be separated by commas" >
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="single-add-property">
                        <h3>Gallery</h3>
                        <div class="property-form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="single-add-property">
                        <h3>Location</h3>

                        <div class="property-form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label for="price">Area Name *</label>
                                <input type="text" id="txtLocation" runat="server" clientidmode="static" placeholder="Enter Area name" class="form-control" />
                                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
                                <script id="rendered-js" type="text/javascript">
                                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
                                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', autoComplete);
                                    var autocomplete;
                                    var map;
                                    var countryRestrict = { 'country': 'pk' };
                                    var markers = [];
                                    var MARKER_PATH = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi.png';
                                    var myPolygon;
                                    function autoComplete() {
                                        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                                            (
                                                document.getElementById('txtLocation')), {

                                                componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
                                            });
                                        //autocomplete.setFields(['address_component']);
                                        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', PointOnMap);
                                    }
                                    function PointOnMap() {
                                        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                                        //alert(place.geometry['location'].lat() + "," + place.geometry['location'].lng());
                                        map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
                                        //map.setOptions({ zoom: 16, minZoom: 10, maxZoom: 19 });
                                        map.setOptions({ zoom: 16 });
                                        AddMarker(place.geometry.location);
                                        document.getElementById("txtAreaLatLng").value = place.geometry.location;
                                        myPolygon.setMap(null);
                                        /*new polygon*/
                                    }

                                    function showInfoWindow() {
                                        //show marker info
                                    }

                                    function AddMarker(latlng) {
                                        var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH;
                                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            map: map,
                                            position: latlng,
                                            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                            icon: markerIcon
                                        });
                                        clearMarkers();
                                        markers.push(marker);
                                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (evt) {
                                            document.getElementById('txtLocLatLng').value = evt.latLng;
                                        });

                                    }
                                    // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
                                    function setMapOnAll(map) {
                                        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                                            markers[i].setMap(map);
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
                                    function clearMarkers() {
                                        setMapOnAll(null);
                                    }

                                    // Shows any markers currently in the array.
                                    function showMarkers() {
                                        setMapOnAll(map);
                                    }

                                    // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
                                    function deleteMarkers() {
                                        clearMarkers();
                                        markers = [];
                                    }

                                    function initialize() {
                                        // Map Center
                                        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.9940812, 67.6751937);
                                        // General Options
                                        var mapOptions = {
                                            zoom: 6,
                                            center: myLatLng,
                                            mapTypeControl: false,
                                            streetViewControl: false,
                                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                                        };

                                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
                                        //var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                                        //    { content: 'Click the map to get Lat/Lng!', position: myLatLng });
                                        //infoWindow.open(map);

                                        // Configure the click listener.
                                        map.addListener('click', function (mapsMouseEvent) {
                                            // Close the current InfoWindow.
                                            //infoWindow.close();
                                            //alert(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toString());
                                            AddMarker(mapsMouseEvent.latLng);
                                            document.getElementById('txtLocLatLng').value = mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toString();
                                            // Create a new InfoWindow.
                                            //infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng });
                                            //infoWindow.setContent(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toString());
                                            //infoWindow.open(map);
                                        });
                                        // Polygon Coordinates


                                    }
                                </script>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtLocLatLng" Style="visibility: hidden;"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="txtAreaLatLng" Style="visibility: hidden;"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="single-add-property">
                        <h3>Contact Information</h3>
                        <div class="property-form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                                    <p>
                                        <label for="con-name">Name *</label>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" runat="server" id="txtContactName" name="con-name">
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                                    <p>
                                        <label for="con-user">Contact Number *</label>
                                        <input type="text" runat="server" ID="txtPhoneNumber" placeholder="Enter Your Contact Number" name="con-user" >
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                                    <p class="no-mb first">
                                        <label for="con-email">Email</label>
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" runat="server" id="txtEmail" name="con-email">
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
                                    <p class="no-mb last">
                                        <label for="con-phn">Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Address Number" runat="server" id="txtAddress" name="con-phn">
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" ValidationGroup="ab1" Display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="add-property-button">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="prperty-submit-button">
                                    <asp:Button ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="Greenbutton" runat="server" 
                                        ID="btnRegister" ValidationGroup="ab1" Text="Regsiter My Business" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- END SECTION SUBMIT PROPERTY -->
</div>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate("ab1");
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            Karobar obj = new Karobar();
            obj.Title = txtTitle.Value.Trim();
            obj.Description = txtDescription.Value.Trim();
            obj.Speciality = txtSpciality.Value.Trim();
            obj.LocationName = txtLocation.Value.Trim();
            obj.ContactName = txtContactName.Value.Trim();
            //obj.ContactPhone = txtPhoneNumber.Value.Trim();
            obj.Email = txtEmail.Value.Trim();
            obj.Address = txtAddress.Value.Trim();
            obj.LocationLat = double.Parse(txtAreaLatLng.Text.Substring(1, txtAreaLatLng.Text.IndexOf(',') - 1));
            obj.LocationLng = double.Parse(txtAreaLatLng.Text.Substring(txtAreaLatLng.Text.IndexOf(',') + 1).Replace(")", ""));
            obj.KarobarLat = double.Parse(txtLocLatLng.Text.Substring(1, txtLocLatLng.Text.IndexOf(',') - 1));
            obj.KarobarLng = double.Parse(txtLocLatLng.Text.Substring(txtLocLatLng.Text.IndexOf(',') + 1).Replace(")", ""));
            obj.Password = Functions.RandomNumericPassword();
            obj.URL = Functions.GetKarobarLink(obj.Title);
            obj.IsActive = true;
            if (KarobarDB.AddKarobar(obj, out int KarobarID))
            {
                if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
                {
                    string SavePath = Server.MapPath("~/karobarimages/" + KarobarID + "/");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(SavePath))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(SavePath);
                    }

                    int count = 0;
                    foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
                    {
                        uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(SavePath, uploadedFile.FileName));
                        KarobarImage objImg = new KarobarImage();
                        objImg.KarobarID = KarobarID;
                        objImg.ImageName = uploadedFile.FileName;
                        if (count == 0)
                        {
                            objImg.IsMainImage = true;
                        }
                        KarobarDB.AddKarobarImage(objImg);
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                Response.Redirect("registration-success.aspx?id=" + KarobarID);
            }
        }
    }
```

in web.config app setting used it for jquery validation

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />

 added only 1 validator for testing in the last for Address field
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: validator not firing on client side but on server side it is validating

Comment: Can you post your markup and code please ?

Comment: can you please review the markup now

Comment: Can I clarify what you're asking because you've said 2 different things so far, is it 
**1)** when you click the submit button, none of the code in the `if (Page.IsValid)` block runs, indicating that the page is not valid i.e. your RequiredFieldValidator is invalid because txtAddress.Text is empty,        or is it 
**2)** when you click the submit button, the client-side validation does not happen, only the server-side validation

Comment: Try enabling unobtrusive and make sure jquery.unobtrusive.js is included on the page.

Comment: @sh1rts you are right client side validation is not happening only server side validation is happening